# DataGridView - how to hide the "new" row?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

My DataGridView is read-only - the user cannot enter data into it, so that empty row at the end (the "new" row?) just looks ugly.

How can I prevent it from displaying?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

On the form designer view, click the little arrow to the right on the DataGridView. Adjust the value for `Enable Adding`.  That will remove the row at the bottom of your grid.

[image]

Programmatically, you can adjust the `AllowUserToAddRows` property.

```
myGrid.AllowUserToAddRows = False
```

Answer (score 10):

The `DataGridView` has a boolean property `AllowUserToAddRows`. Set this to false and you should no longer see the empty row at the end of the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Just a clarification for other people who are looking at this for WPF the datagrid property has been renamed to `CanUserAddRows`